# How to create a dynamic class name by concatening with an index?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have a collapsable accordeon in my Razor page. I want to create a dynamical class name, as the amount of panels in my accordeon can vary. I loop over the items of my model. For each item, I create a panel. I do this with @for.

For example, I want something of the form like this as the actual result:

```
<!-- Other HTML code-->
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<!-- Other HTML code-->
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<!-- Other HTML code-->
<div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<!-- Other HTML code-->
```

So I want to concatenate the index of my @for-loop with the id "collapse".
How can I do something like this with Razor page syntax?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to concatenate the index of my @for-loop with the id
> "collapse". How can I do something like this with Razor page syntax?

In the For-Loop, you could define a variable to store the id value, after that assign it to the `<div>` element. Code like this:

```
@for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    var idvalue = "collapse" + @i;

    <div id="@idvalue" class="panel-collapse collapse show">
        content @i
    </div>
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

Besides, you could also add a `_` between the `collapse` and the index value, code as below:

```
@for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{ 
    <div id="collapse_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse show">
        content @i
    </div>
}
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]